# HTTP Server in Chrome Packaged App using Sockets API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to get a simple web page server from within a Google Chrome Packaged App. There is already a UDP server running within the app and working without any problems.

I am starting the socket.listen on `0.0.0.0:8080` and copying most of the code from

```
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/webserver
```

. The same issue is replicated in the sample app.

What I am doing is accepting the request and sending a single HTML file to all requests which have some data in the request (`request.data.length > 0`). The flow of the app is similar to the sample app with near-equivalent functions.

To test this I am using `Socket Test 3.0` (from SourceForge). Creating a socket to `127.0.0.1:8080` and sending it `GET / HTTP/1.1` as the content. As intended the Chrome App responds with the html file and correct headers. I can repeat this multiple times without restarting the App. The problem arises when the App is sent a request through Chrome. On first look it works as intended, but then it *Time Out* on refresh. This is also replicated in the sample app.

On debugging I found that every thing was being handles. The write socket being destroyed and a `socket.accept(serverSocket, ...)` being issued. I also made sure that it was done inside the callback function of the `socket.write`. The first request as intended is for the page requested (`GET / HTTP/1.1` for `localhost:8080`). Second was for favicon.ico as `GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1`. And then a third connection with none in data (which is then ignored and socket destroyed). Unlike in the SocketTest where every request was answered back.

I have created a video showing the screencast while reproducing the error on [YouTube](http://youtu.be/W5-0PDgJSJw). Also the repo for the project that I'm working on is at [GitHub](https://github.com/shantanuthatte/OSC_Server).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Google's sample web server. I wrote a more robust socket server app that does not hang. The source is on GitHub at https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome and you can install it from the Chrome web store at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb